# tetxbox with drop down control and auto complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

in my Application i have text box beside it i have  drop down control.

when the user  clicks on the  drop down  . a list of  items  under the  drop  down  control  should be  shown.  but  if  user  type  any  value in the  text box  ( like    tom, james, peter). if that  value   is there  in the  drop  down . i  should  move the  cursor  to  that  value.

hope  my  Question is  clear.
  Any  solution  how  to  solve   it  would  be  great
  thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you looking is,

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

Just check it, Its autocomplete with dropdown

Comment: Yeap- I think that looks more like it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like the [JQuery autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) or if you prefer the [ASP.NET AJAX Autocomplete control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

Edit- as you want a Combobox- JQuery has a lot of options for this. Here is one of them ["Simple Combo"](http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/resources/simpleCombo-demo.html).

Comment: more  like  i  wanted  an    comobox  control   for  web  application with auto  complete  control